# How to sniff Bluetooth traffic in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, packet-sniffers, android-bluetooth

I would like to know if there are any apps/api tools to track all the bluetooth connections happening in android? I tried using *hcidump* via BusyBox, but the trace is truncated, it does not display all the data I need.

I am trying to receive data from blood pressure monitor in android using Bluetooth HDP profile. However, the connection works at the beginning, and then stops. Therefore, I would like to use some packet sniffer to see the low level bluetooth connection for better debugging.

Comment: See this newer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761/sniffing-logging-your-own-android-bluetooth-traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that traces from *hcidump* tools are not truncated, and I think this is a perfect solution. However, I have to copy the trace from android to the pc evry time (e.g. sending by e-mail) and therefore it is a cumbersome work. Would be great if there was a tool to get access to the terminal emulator of android. Btw, BusyBox provides also some other very useful tools from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this currently, the first is to use a software-defined radio that supports the ISM band (at least 2.4 to 2.485 GHz). This will allow you to grab any radio signals within the bluetooth range and will be especially useful if you're trying to identify interfering signals.

The downside is that you'll be receiving totally raw waveforms which you then need to demodulate using something like the gr-bluetooth stack.

The other option is a specialized device like the Ubertooth.